# error in ftp while uplodaing/downloading

Tags: sftp

This year, in my engineering class, we are learning OS and Doing Shell Programming.
I keep a backup of my work on FTP which used to work fine, but now I am getting this error, while uploading and download to the server:

```
ftp> dir
500 I won't open a connection to 10.23.28.243 (only to 1.23.149.28)
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

&

```
ftp> put asdf.sh
local: asdf.sh remote: asdf.sh
500 I won't open a connection to 10.23.28.243 (only to 1.23.149.28)
```

I don't have college server access, please help me with this problem.

Comment: Is the server listening on port 21?  Do you have a firewall running?

Comment: yes for web access protection they have college level firewall

Comment: You need to allow access to port 21 in the firewall.  Try ftp -p what happens?

Comment: The Worked Really Fine. All problems Solved
Thank you So Much :)

please make this Answer Solved so Other May Get HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that  the server is listening on port 21, and that the port is allowed in the firewall rules.

You could also try using passive mode by doing ftp -p